# What is another way of saying "less premium?"

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives, synonyms

I'm looking for another way to say "less premium." This is the context:

> The competition's brand was less premium.

I do not want to change the overall structure of the sentence. This is not a super complex question, but I am having a difficult time with it. Thank you!

Comment: The usage of _premium_ usually means "high quality" or "high value". The Online Etymology Dictionary says "superior in quality".  The problem with crafting a good sentence is that there's no context for the sentence you've offered. Who's it being written for? What's the product? Can you comment specifically on the quality or value of their product compared with yours? Saying that something was "less premium" can mean only that it costs less: premium brands are always more expensive than other brands, but that's no assurance that their quality & value are greater than the cheaper brand.

Comment: Have you tried looking up "premium" in a thesaurus? It will give you a list of words with similar meanings, and you can decide if one of them works for you.

Comment: The competition's brand was sub-premium. Are you sure it's a "was" and not an "is"?

Answer (score 4):

*Inferior*

> *Adjective* — Lower in rank, status, or quality.
>
> *Synonym* — Subordinate

Comment: Good suggestion. You might want to include a link to your source, or if it's not online, mention where your definition and synonym came from.

Answer (score 1):

As @Bill comments, *premium* in this context usually means "high quality" - often relating to the fact that you'll ***pay*** a [premium](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/premium) *(money paid in addition to a regular price)* for such products.

Thus, products which *don't* have this extra quality could be called "standard" or "cheaper" - or more likely in OP's exact context, ***lower quality***.